# react chart js, title is not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, jsx

I'm using react chart js to show a doughnut in my component.

```
"chart.js": "^3.7.1",
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.1.0",
```

I'm not able to show the title :

```
const data = {
  labels: ["Score", "Total"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Indice d'impact global de la transaction",
      data: [3.7, 5],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(128,128,128,0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(54, 162, 235, 1", "rgba(128,128,128,1)"],
      borderWidth: 1,
      lineTension: 0.5,
    },
  ],
};

<Doughnut
options={{
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Indice d'impact global de la transaction",
      align: "center",
      padding: {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 30,
      },
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "top",
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
    },
  },
}}
data={data}
/>
```

How can i correclty show the title ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you are using treeshaking and not importing and registering the `Title`

To fix it either import and registr every component you are using, list of all components can be found [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) like so:

```
import {Chart, Title} from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(Title);
```

Or use the auto import to let chart.js register everything for you:

```
import 'chart.js/auto'
```

Comment: For people having the same with Legend. Same solution             

import {Chart, Title, Legend} from 'chart.js'
Chart.register(Legend);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

a) Ensure you have installed chart.js:

`npm install chart.js`

b) Import Chart and Title as shown below:

```
import { Chart, Title } from "chart.js";
```

c) Register Title as show below:

```
Chart.register(Title);
```

d) Then set the title as given below:

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
     title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Bar Chart'
      }
   }
}
```